# php upload_max_filesize ignored - unable to upload 5gb file

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, upload

I'm unable to upload files larger than roughly 2gb.  The max upload/post values were previously set to 2500MB so I thought that was the problem.

First,

```
# php --version
PHP 5.3.3 (cli)
```

I set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` as follows

```
# vi /etc/php.ini
post_max_size = 5500M
upload_max_filesize = 5500M
[write/quit vi]
```

Next,

```
# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

I then confirmed the new configuration with a phpinfo() script:

```
post_max_size   5500M   5500M
upload_max_filesize 5500M   5500M
```

I go back to my script to upload another large data file (~4GB), and am again told that the uploaded file exceeds value of `upload_max_filesize`.

So, I am at a loss.  I am able to upload 2gb and smaller files no problem.   I've restarted Apache, and don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Exactly what operating system, distribution, etc.?

Comment: CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2

Comment: Does the application you're using have a file size limit? For example, MediaWiki has its own limit defined in LocalSettings.php.

Comment: It does and the file size limit matches what is in php.ini.   The software (VIMP) is known to work just fine with very large files ( >5gb )

Answer (score 1):

This PHP-Change log

http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.0

states that, until PHP 5.6.0, file uploads were limited to 2 GB.

Answer (score 0):

You may be updating the wrong file.  Verify with the `php -i` command.  For example:

```
$ php -i 2> /dev/null | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Comment: Testing with `php -i` may still give him the wrong file.  It isn't uncommon to have a completely different config for the CLI vs the Apache module, or CGI.

Comment: I'm updating the correct file because if I change `upload_max_filesize` to 9999M, then restart apache, I see that reflected in `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are using a 32 bit operating system. If that is the case you won't be able to go beyond 2GB with apache and PHP.

See this article for more information: http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/admin_manual/configuration/configuring_big_file_upload.html

Comment: 64 bit CentOS with 24gb RAM.  Wondering if I have a 32-bit version of Apache installed now.  How would I find that out?

Comment: `$ file /usr/sbin/httpd`
/usr/sbin/httpd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

Comment: is there an error message in error_log?

Comment: ooo till Monday, can't get to my video production machine.  will follow up then (and delete this message at that time)